# Get cell value based on its rank position from an input raster collection

Tags: qgis, raster, rank

I have a QGIS overlapping five-raster set, and I want to get the third-ranking value for each cell from these rasters. How can I get this value by considering the five values of this cell in the five different rasters?

Comment: The third-ranked value in a set of five is always the median, isn't it?

Comment: Yes, you're right, it is.

Answer (score 1):

If you're willing to try GRASS GIS, then the module `r.series` ([man page](https://grass.osgeo.org/grass78/manuals/r.series.html)) can calculate the median value (based on @Vince's hint) of a series of rasters, puxel by pixel. The input to the module would be the list of all 5 rasters, the method would be `median`, and the output raster would contain the median values.

Comment: That's it, thank you a lot! Even the other quantiles, we can also get them.